# How to print react select state in another component?

Tags: reactjs, select

I am trying to print state of select element in the footer. But the problem is that it does not print anything because the default value is null. And I dont know how to print footer on change of select with state of the select inside.

```
    class SingleColor extends React.Component {
      state = {
        selectedOption: null,
      };
      handleChange = selectedOption => {
        this.setState({ selectedOption });
      };
      render() {
        const { selectedOption } = this.state;
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            <h1 className="TITLE">Please choose your favourite colour</h1>
            <Select 
              className="SINGLESELECT"
              classNamePrefix="SINGLESELECT__options"
              value={selectedOption}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              options={options} 
              styles={customStyles}
            />
            <Footer singlevalue={this.state.selectedOption} />
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      }
    }
```

```
    export default class Footer extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="bla">
            <h1> {this.props.singlevalue}</h1>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

Comment: what does the `onChange` of the `Select` component emit? Does it emit an event or does it emit the changed value?

Comment: Which select you are using? A react-select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s because onChange event doesn’t send the value directly but an event.

```
handleChange = event => { 
  const { value } = event.target
  this.setState({ selectedOption: value })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using `react-select`.

When you change value, `react-select` give you object as you provided array of object to `options`.

You should print value in `Footer` component as,

```
<h1> {this.props.singlevalue && this.props.singlevalue.label}</h1>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jn1a4b)